# why do i remove turbolinks before using angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

```
gem install rails -v 4.1
rails new angular_example
```

Before using angular i'm recommended to remove turbolinks.
So why do i have to remove it and what's the purpose of turbolinks?

Comment: Did you mean "turbolinks"?

Comment: sorry for wrong spells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Angular and Turbolinks can conflict with one another,angular doesn't work correctly. So we disable turbolinks.

Turbolinks handle the request made by browser. For example  AJAX request to the server, waiting the answer, deleting the old content and replacing it with the new content

Comment: the reason why turbolinks must  be removed is okay.
But the aim of using turbolinks or purpose are poor.

Comment: Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. It keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head. These are turbolinks tech and you use turbolinks with angular, there will be conflict with requests.